# Is it possible to use the "try" Function on an "if" statement?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, try-catch, except

In my program I have this 2D array:

```
Test=[
  ["TestName", "123", "1", "2.5"],
  ["NameTest", "321", "10", "5.2"],
  ["jpoj", "321", "10", "5.2"],
  ["OIAN","oihadIH","oihda","iohda"]
]
```

And, in a `while` loop, in a `for i in range` function, there's this `if` statement:

```
if Test[i][r]==search:
```

(`r` is just a variable that gets higher each while iteration).

When it gets to this point, if the `r` variable is too high, it gives an `IndexError`.

**Is there a way I can use something like the `try:` and `except()` functions on it?**

Here was my failed attempt at it:

```
try:
    if Test[i][r]==search:
except(IndexError):
    r=0
```

The whole code is here if you wish to see it:

```
stop=False
stop2=False
import time

Test=[
  ["TestName", "123", "1", "2.5"],
  ["NameTest", "321", "10", "5.2"],
  ["jpoj", "321", "10", "5.2"],
  ["OIAN","oihadIH","oihda","iohda"]
]
r=0

search=input("Search: ")

for i in range(len(Test)):
  while stop!=True:
    try:
        if Test[i][r]==search:
          print(Test[i])
          stop=True

        else:
          try:
            r=r+1
          except(IndexError):
            r=0
    except(IndexError):
      r=0
      i=0

while stop2!=True:
  try:
    print(Test[0][r]," | ", end='')
  except IndexError:
    stop2=True
  r=r+1
```

Comment: you should include your current attempt and explain what "didnt work" means

Comment: Do you mean to just do something like `if Test[i][r]==search and r < (len(Test[i]) - 1)`?

Comment: You could wrap the if statement in a try and then catch IndexError however it would be better to change the loop so the index error doesn't occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my take on this:

```
import time
stop=False
stop2=False

Test=[
  ["TestName", "123", "1", "2.5"],
  ["NameTest", "321", "10", "5.2"],
  ["jpoj", "321", "10", "5.2"],
  ["OIAN","oihadIH","oihda","iohda"]
]
r=0

search=input("Search: ")

for idx, lst in enumerate(Test):
    if search in lst:
        for index, value in enumerate(lst):
            if search == value:
                print(f"Word: {search} found in list: {idx} and index: {index}")
```

Results:

```
Search: 10
Word: 10 found in list: 1 and index: 2
Word: 10 found in list: 2 and index: 2

Search: OIAN  
Word: OIAN found in list: 3 and index: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for row in Test:
    for item in row:
        if item == search:
            # do stuff
```

This is a better way to loop through a 2d array. If you need to get the index you could add 2 counter variables to track it. This way prevents the IndexError rather than having to try catch it.

Answer (score 0):

You have need to indent your `if` statement and `pass` an empty block if you aren't running any commands:

```py
try:
    if Test[i][r] == search:
        # Insert code here, and remove pass
        pass
except IndexError:
    r = 0
```

---

But it seems you're re-inventing `.index()` on the first element. You can use:

```
try:
    print(Test[[x[0] for x in Test].index(search)])
except ValueError:
    print(f"{search} is not in the list")
```

Examples:

```
Search: TestName
['TestName', '123', '1', '2.5']
```

```
Search: Foo
Foo is not in the list
```

---

You could add some QOL aspects to this new method:

- `.strip()`

  - To remove whitespace
- `.lower()`

  - To be case intensive
- `.join()`

  - For a clean output

```py
try:
    print(", ".join(Test[[x[0].lower() for x in Test].index(search.lower().strip())]))
except ValueError:
    print(f"{search} is not in the list")
```

```
Search: nametest
NameTest, 321, 10, 5.2
```

Answer (score 0):

A better implementation of what you propose is through a condition if you make sure that we are within the allowed range:

```
if r < len(Test[i])
```

If you still want to do it with try and except you must add those clauses enclosing the exception in which the exception is produced.
In this case at the time you access Test[i][r]. NOT ELSEWHERE

```
try: 
   a = Test[i][r]
except(IndexError):
   a = 0
   print("error")
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply try to subscript the `Test` matrix...

```
try:
    Test[i][r]
except(IndexError):
    r=0
```

You don't need the `if` in this case.